# How to get First OR Second Row

Tags: sql

I would like to display the First OR Second Value
(based on Certain First_Value Condition)

```
FIRST_VALUE (
                         A_DATE IGNORE NULLS)
                     OVER (PARTITION BY APP_NO, APPL_NO
                           ORDER BY A_DATE DESC)
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and tag your DBMS (Mysql, MS, Oracle...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ORDER BY clause to get the first or the second  row of a table:

to get the  first row :

```
select *from yourTableName order by yourColumnName ASC LIMIT 1;
```

to get the second row :

```
select *from yourTableName order by yourColumnName ASC LIMIT 1,1;
```